# How can I "install" fonts to use in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: fonts, mono

I have this beautiful mono font https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode that I'd like to use in Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu.

I downloaded the font files (.ttf), I understood that to make a font systemwide available I have to copy it to `/usr/share/fonts`, so I sudo-copied those files to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fira-code`

I noticed the premissions after the copy were 750, so I chmoded to 755

Now I go to the Visual Studio Code preferences and tell it I will use "Fira Code", and does nothing. If I change it to "DejaVu Sans Mono" for example, it will use that font.

**Doing this, I don't see the fonts in LibreOffice, either**.

After this fail, I created a `.fonts` directory on my home and copied the .ttf files, same result. (I followed the instructons here: https://itsfoss.com/install-fonts-ubuntu-1404-1410/)

**Copying the fonts here, I see them in LibreOffice, but I can't use them in Visual Studio Code**

So looks like there most be some kind of "font registry" sort to speak, how do you correctly install font files in Ubuntu?

Comment: The FiraCode developer's github page says Visual Studio Code is supported. Perhaps you can get help from the developer?

Comment: I think this is in general, not related specifically to this font

Comment: ...or could be a configuration thing on VSC

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To set this beautiful fonts up use the following steps

1. Download the fonts from [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#download-v1206--how-to-install--troubleshooting--news--updates)
2. Unzip and in the `ttf` folder double click each file and select `install` from the dialogue box that appears
3. Setup VSCode:

   1. Open `File -> Preferences -> Settings`
   2. Top right click on `{}` and the `user settings` (settings.json) will open up
   3. Add the following lines:

      ```
      "editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code'",
      "editor.fontLigatures": true,
      ```

      - Note: I had to comment out the normal `font family entry` which I can switch back to by reversing the process.
   4. To change the font weight add any of the following lines but not all

      ```
      "editor.fontWeight": "300" // Light
      "editor.fontWeight": "400" // Regular
      "editor.fontWeight": "500" // Medium
      "editor.fontWeight": "600" // Bold
      ```
4. Restart and enjoy.

   [image]

My sample user settings.json

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "vsicons.projectDetection.autoReload": true,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false,
    // "editor.fontFamily": "'Noto Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle",
    // "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code', 'Noto Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    // "editor.fontWeight": "300", // Light
    // "editor.fontWeight": "400", // Regular
    // "editor.fontWeight": "500", // Medium
    // "editor.fontWeight": "600" // Bold
}
```